# How to show product from parent category in child category archive, in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, taxonomy

I need to customize the product category archive template.
I want to show parent category products in a child category archive template.

For details lets assume these categories:-

- All
- business (child of All)
- Work from home (child of business)
- online business (child of business)

Current if we open the archive for "All" then all post form child category (business, Work from home, online business ) will show and if we open the archive for "Business" then all post form child category (Work from home, online business) will show.
And this default functionality of wordpress or woocommerce.
But I need that if archive for "online business" (child category) opened

- then show products from this selected category (online business).
- also show post from all parent categories (All,Business) of this
  category.

Comment: Any code you have done for this question? Show you code progress and I can help you to find a problem.

Comment: I did not find any code or solution, i am unable to understand that how to achieve this. Please help me if you can provide me a solution to make this possible.

Comment: I tried with this code:

`function include_parent($wp_query) {
    if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxomony'] ) ) {
        $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( array (
            'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxonomy'],
            'include_children' => true,
           'include_parent' => true
        ) )
    }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'include_parent');`

But its not working @ArtemAnokhin
Please help me to solve achieve this.